# Problems with converting type int? to int. Missing a cast?

Tags: c#

I am trying to pull a date from a separate program and use it to determine the expiration dates of contracts. I have called int's for the month day and year and then used DateTime to assign to another var.

I am fairly new to C# and and can't find a work around for the error I get with this block. The errors tell me that it cannot implicitly convert int? to int, when I use an int? var to declare the day month and year it then shifts the error down to the DateTime line.

This probably needs to be structured differently but I can't figure out what that way would be.

```
private Instrument m_instr = null;

private void m_getInstrDetails(Instrument instr)
{
    m_ContractName = instr.Name.ToString();
    m_type = instr.Product.Type.ToString();
    m_prod = instr.Product.ToString();
    m_SmallestTickIncrtement = instr.InstrumentDetails.SmallestTickIncrement;


    //month calc
    int month = m_instr.InstrumentDetails.ExpirationDate.Month; 
    int day = m_instr.InstrumentDetails.ExpirationDate.Day;
    int year = m_instr.InstrumentDetails.ExpirationDate.Year;

    m_expDate1 = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

Comment: Well presumably `ExpirationDate.Month` is of type `int?`, not `int`. It's hard to tell without a `[mcve]`. (We have no idea what the `Instrument` type is, for a start.)

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the value is `null`?

Comment: Please provide the `Intrument` and `InstrumentDetails` definitions.

Comment: Yes the ExpirationDate.Month is int?, and the inst is  private Instrument m_instr = null;

Comment: Are those values optional? if not then throw exception. `if(day.HasValue == false) throw new ArgumentException()` other wise provide default value instead, `day ?? 1`

Comment: ExpirationDate.Value.Year

Comment: @MMK `ExpirationDate.Year.Value` when `Year` is nullable

Comment: OK @MatthiasBurger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int?` is a `Nullable`-type, that means, that your `int` also could be `null`.

You get the value by

```
int? month = m_instr.InstrumentDetails.ExpirationDate.Month;
int month = month.Value;
```

you could check, if `month` is not `null` by

```
bool monthIsNotNull = month.HasValue;
```

because you could get an exception when trying to initialize the `DateTime`-variable when `month` is `null` - or at least, when trying to get `int` via `month.Value` and `month` is `null`

the `DateTime`-constructor wants `DateTime(int year, int month, int day)` - he doesn't want to get e.g. a month that's `null`

Answer (score 3):

A nullable integer (`int?`) cannot be cast to a traditional integer (`int`) since there are scenarios where one might be null, and you'll need to determine how you want to handle such occasions.

**Consider Parsing or Using a Default Value**

You need to determine what you want to occur when your nullable value is null. Nullable integers by default expose a [`HasValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which you can use to determine as a default or you could consider using the null-propagation operator to handle this :

```
// This will use the expiration date if it exists, otherwise it will use 1
int month = m_instr.InstrumentDetails.ExpirationDate?.Month ?? 1;
```

Another option involves setting an initial value and using the [`int.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) method to update the value prior to use :

```
int month = 1;
int.TryParse(m_instr.InstrumentDetails.ExpirationDate?.Month, out month);
```

**Considering Throwing an Exception**

If you don't want to allow these types of scenarios to occur and using some default value isn't feasible, you could consider just throwing an exception :

```
if(!month.HasValue) { throw ArgumentException("month"); }
```

You can allow this to bubble up to the appropriate location and handle it accordingly within your application (i.e. notify the user, log the problem, etc.)

Comment: for null-propagation-operator and setting a default-value in one line +1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `ExpirationDate.<properties>` are your `int?` s, if the concern is whether or not there is an `ExpirationDate`, shouldn't you see if *that* is `null` instead?  Then you could just use regular `ints` as properties of an `ExpirationDate` object.:

```
    private void m_getInstrDetails(Instrument instr)
    {
        m_ContractName = instr.Name.ToString();
        m_type = instr.Product.Type.ToString();
        m_prod = instr.Product.ToString();
        m_SmallestTickIncrtement = instr.InstrumentDetails.SmallestTickIncrement;

        if(InstrumentDetails.ExpirationDate != null)
        {
          //if you change the .Month, .Day, and .Year to int, and test against
          //ExpirationDate, this will work fine                        
          //month calc
          int month = m_instr.InstrumentDetails.ExpirationDate.Month; 
          int day = m_instr.InstrumentDetails.ExpirationDate.Day;
          int year = m_instr.InstrumentDetails.ExpirationDate.Year;
           m_expDate1 = new DateTime(year, month, day);
         }
    }
```